# Gson didnt support MutableLiveData <model> in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, gson

I have the following code, I receive the following exception when I deserilize the response to a Gson from JSON:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.model.photos.photosModel cannot be cast to androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
```

This is my My code when I receive the response from the server:

```
  lateinit var _photosModel:MutableLiveData<photosModel>

  val gson = Gson()
            val modelObj = gson.fromJson<Any>(response.toString(), photosModel::class.java)
            _photosModel = modelObj as MutableLiveData<photosModel>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply because you are parsing from Json to model is Any that while you are needing type `MutableLiveData`.

And more thing, if you want to set data for `MutableLiveData`, you should use 2 methods `setValue()` if you want to set value in main thread and `postValue()` if you want to set value in other thread.

Just like that:

*YourViewModel.kt*

```
private val _photosModel = MutableLiveData<PhotosModel>()
val photosModel: LiveData<PhotosModel> = _photosModel

val gson = Gson()
val modelObj: PhotosModel = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), PhotosModel::class.java) // You should make the first letter of the class uppercase.

// Set value for mutable livedata
_photosModel.value = modelObj
```

Comment: @OsamaIbrahim Hope you give me an upvote and accept my answer by [click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you.